# Smarty template add to a variable error

Tags: php, smarty

Im trying to

```
    {$mouseOver = "test"}
    {$mouseOver .= " continue"}
```

Like i can do this in simple php:

```
$test = "Hello";
$test .= " continue";

echo $test; // will output: Hello continue
```

In Smarty PHP template. How can i do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[v2p](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8233859/398242) is on the right track, but specifically you would do it like this:

```
{assign var="varname" value="Hello"}
{assign var="varname" value="{$varname} World"}

{$varname}
```

This would print "Hello World", and `$varname` would continue to hold that value until further modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try `{assign var='name' value='some value'}`

See http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign

---

What about string concatenation, use `cat` modifier

See http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.cat